# What are "Waits" in the AWS RDS performance insights dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm dealing with some performance issues in my AWS RDS database.

I don't understand what I'm seeing under the "waits" dimension:

[image: Waits dimension]

The values in this dimension are concatenated stringslike `wait/synch/mutex/innodb/trx_pool_ma...`

Where are they coming from?

Where can I find what each of them means?

How can I handle them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Those look like Aurora MySQL wait events.**

A full list of them are available in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Tuning.wait-events.html).

Clicking through to individual pages for each - e.g. [`io/table/sql/handler`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/ams-waits.waitio.html) - you will get a description, context, likely causes & ultimately actions to take for remedy.

[image]